# Magento per physical store pricing

Tags: magento

I'm currently developing a Magento based webstore which will need the ability to:

1. Allow a customer to view and select a default physical store
2. Display different pricing, based on the store they have selected
3. Not show any prices if they have not selected a default store, but still allow the user to view the product.

I've seen questions regarding tiered pricing, could I use this to identify a "customer group" -> that is allow the customer to select the store (and hence the group) they belong to?

Or should I go down the route of setting up a Magento store per physical store?

I'm at a loss as to the best route on this on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an update on how I ended up doing this:

1. Created a Customer Group per physical store
2. Allow the users to select which store (i.e. Customer Group) they wish to shop in
3. Added tiered pricing, per Customer Group, ensuring the price of the item is actually the maximum price possible for that item. If you don't make this the maximum then the tiered price won't show.
4. Changed the product list to show the tiered price, and the view page to show the tiered price without the "as low as" text

Possibly not the nicest way of doing things, but we didn't want to set up a store per physical store.

The only issue we ended up with here is that the special prices won't work as per normal. It's possible for us to have specials priced differently per store. 
To work around this we have implemented Catalog Price rules instead of special prices.

Hope this helps someone